# How to make sure one function is invoked only once in a period?

Tags: python, django, email, scheduled-tasks

There is a chatting app which can transmit the message to my server, I do it because I want to save all the message record on my own server. Basically the chatting app send messages to the certain url, and I use Django to save them, I have done it already, I use a function called `save_message(request)` to save them(just write the messages to a text file).

And now I want to write a program on the server which can send me an email when the message comes to the server, I have done it as well, I use a function called `send_email()` to do it.

However, the problem is, I want to send email **periodically**.

For example:

- If the server receives 1000 messages in 2 hours, I just want to receive one email.That is to say, this email will be sent once the first message is received, and for the rest of 2 hours, whether there are new messages, I won't receive any messages.
- If the server doesn't receive any messages in 2/4/8/... hours, then I won't receive any emails.

I think every time the server receives message, it needs to invoke `save_message(request)`, and also I think the `send_email()` invocation should be in the body of `save_message(request)`, I don't know how to skip this invocation at certain time. Is it possible to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Write a function called send_email_if_desired. It checks if the last mail was sent >2h ago, and if so calls send_email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `django-crontab` and specify the time in the setting.py for the fucntion you want to run after how much time

Comment: Thank you, it helps